# Existing VBA Macro from Windows 7/Excel 2010 Fails to Save .xlsm for some users upgraded to Win10/Excel 365

Tags: vba, windows-10, excel-365

There are many questions like this one on the internet, but none of them has led me to a solution. Hopefully, I can find some relief here.

I have a community of users who are currently going through a migration from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and along with it, a migration from Office 2010 to Office 365. As a result of this migration, SOME (not all) of my users have begun to experience an issue with a macro that worked fine in Win7/Excel 2010, but now throws an error in Win10/Excel365. The specific line of code that is failing is an *application.saveas* statement:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

I have tested and/or checked the following:

- That the entire path name is correct, ie there are no unexpected characters in it, it points to a valid networked location, nothing is misspelled, etc. This is definitely not the problem. Also, the path being used is a fully qualified network path (using the computer name itself, not a letter drive). AND, the users having trouble get no relief when I switch the path to C:\Users<username>\filename
- Swapping out `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` with `FileFormat:=52` ;; No dice
- Swapping out the entire line of code for a SaveAs dialog box that is properly filled in. The same error is produced at the Execute command. Code below:

  ```
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .FilterIndex = 2  '2 = xlsm
       .InitialFileName = myFileName
       .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
       If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
       .Execute ''''Run time error 10004005 "Document not saved" error happens here
   End With
  ```
- Checked a user's add-ins; nothing of interest was found here. They had different add-ins than me, but I had them disable ALL add-ins and this still didn't work
- Went through a user's entire trust center and lined it up as best I could with my own (my machine works fine). We found one setting that we though was worth changing, but it had no effect
- I am ensured that the users who have experienced the problem so far have (like me) received fully new computers with the new OS/Office version installed clean. So I have ruled this out as the cause.
- I have run the macro successfully with graphics acceleration turned off and turned on, thus ruling out that issue (this was causing other Excel problems when I first upgraded).

Any thoughts from the community on what else I might consider or try would be appreciated as I am totally stumped at this point on what to try next.

Thanks!

Comment: "Document not saved" is the whole error, and that's consistent across the various fixes you tried?

Comment: Correct. It comes with error code 10004005 and reads simply, "Document not saved".